# change full name of states to abbreviation with join on table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, one table is called customerAccount, the other is state. I have a lot more data that is being added everyday to this CustomerAccount table. I have multiple instances where the state has its full name and it is supposed to be abbreviated. I want to be able to abbreviate where state is not abbreviated and I want it to do it on every instance when the table is loaded. where not only can I fix the ones not correct right now, but it will fix the ones coming into the table later. Please help me understand how to do this by giving some examples please

CustomerAccount table:

```
RecoverDate Score   City    Company State
2019-02-15  1238    ATLANTA FORD    GA
2019-03-23  2678    ORLANDO ACURA   FLORIDA
```

States table:

```
StateCode   StateName         StateID
AK          ALASKA                      1
AL           ALABAMA                2
AR          ARKANSAS                3
AZ           ARIZONA                 4
CA         CALIFORNIA                5
CO           COLORADO                6
CT           CONNECTICUT                 7
DE          DELAWARE                 8
FL          FLORIDA                      9
GA         GEORGIA                       10
IA         IOWA                      11
ID          IDAHO                        12
IL        ILLINOIS                       13
IN           INDIANA                 14
KS         KANSAS                        15
KY       KENTUCKY                       16
MD         MARYLAND                      17
OH          OHIO                         18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to just use a left join from the `CustomerAccount` table to the `States` table and conditionally replace the two letter state code with the full name:

```
SELECT
    ca.RecoverDate,
    ca.Score,
    ca.City,
    ca.Company
    COALESCE(s.StateName, ca.State) AS State
FROM CustomerAccount ca
LEFT JOIN States s
    ON ca.State = s.StateCode;
```

The logic here is that if a given `State` value in `CustomerAccount` does *not* match to the `States` table, we stick with the current value, otherwise we pull in the mapped full state name.

To get all abbreviations use:

```
SELECT
    ca.RecoverDate,
    ca.Score,
    ca.City,
    ca.Company
    COALESCE(s.StateCode, ca.State) AS State
FROM CustomerAccount ca
LEFT JOIN States s
    ON ca.State = s.StateName
```

Comment: Yes, it should.  Why not try it?

Comment: It made all the states the full name, is there a way to make all of them abbreviated?